# Indian passport binding loose

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, passports, damaged-passports

My passport binding has become loose. Do I need to get a new passport or is this fine?

[image: front binding loose]

[image: back]

Answer (score 4):

There are many similar questions here about **replacing** worn or damaged or lost Indian passports (getting a new passport with a new passport number), and **reissuing** Indian passports (getting a new passport with the same number as your old passport). You can search for those questions and answers using the "Search on Travel" box at the top of the page.

Assuming the data, photo, and chip are present and readable, the answer is a matter of opinion. If you're confident the booklet will not further deteriorate and won't come apart in your pocket, then travel with it.

An immigration officer (from any country) might tell you its too worn or damaged to use, but if the data, photo, and chip are present, will probably not refuse you entry or passage. An immigration officer from a country other than India, however, is unlikely know the difference between "replacement" and "reissue" as set forth in Indian law.

If you're not sure or are nervous about its condition, have it reissued.

Answer (score 1):

I submitted my passport in a similar state for renewal and they rejected citing the booklet binding has been damaged.

Comment: You have to pay extra fees for "damaged passport".